# Is MSDN referencing a system.thread, a worker thread, an I/O thread or all three?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

Please see the warning below taken from the [`StreamWriter` class specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx):

> "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

I understand that a W3WC process contains two thread pools i.e. worker threads and I/O threads.  A worker thread could contain many threads of its own (if the application creates its own `System.Thread` instances).

Does the warning only relate to `System.Threads` or does it relate to worker threads and I/O threads as well I.e. as the instance variables of the `StreamWriter` class are not thread safe then does this mean that there would be problems if multiple worker threads access it, e.g. if two users on two different web clients attempt to write to the log file at the same time, then could one lock out the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class isn't threadsafe, then you can't take an instance of that class and use that instance from more than one thread. It doesn't matter whether they're `System.Threading.Thread` or `ThreadPool` or `Task` or worker threads within IIS. They're all threads -- they're all preemptive multitasking while the object is in a state where it doesn't expect to be preempted.

That doesn't matter in the scenario you describe, though. Suppose two Web clients try to connect to the server at the same time, and your request handler tries to log to a file, meaning you've got two threads potentially trying to write to that file simultaneously. But that's not a thread-safety issue, because you wouldn't be using the same `StreamWriter` instance in both threads. (At least, I hope not -- if you have a static `StreamWriter` instance, how would you ever know when to flush it and close the file? Sharing the same writer across threads wouldn't make any sense.)

Instead, each thread should create its own `StreamWriter`, write to it, and then close it. Yes, there are still concurrency issues -- if the first thread hasn't closed the file yet when the second thread tries to open the file, then the second thread would get a file-sharing exception, and you would need to catch that exception and retry -- but that's a file-locking issue, not a thread-safety issue.

Comment: Thanks +1. Is it fair to say that worker threads and io threads can only be effected by threading issues if static variables or functions are used?

Comment: No, you can easily pass object references across threads without using statics. As one example, the startup thread might create an object instance, and then pass it (perhaps via variable capture in a closure) into code that runs in a thread. Anyplace you might be accessing an object instance from more than one thread, you need to be aware of thread safety, and add locks wherever necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how instance variables can be shared accross worker threads. Could you provide an example?

Comment: A few ways, just off the top of my head: Pass a `state` parameter to [`QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx). Create a [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx) and pass an instance method as the delegate (now that whole instance is shared with the thread). Start a task with a closure: `var myObject = new MyClass(); Task.Run(() => myObject.DoSomething());` Or anything else that passes an object instance into the thread's code.

Comment: Thanks, but the threads in your last comment are system.thread not worker threads.

Comment: Ah, do system.threads create new worker threads? I am new to threading.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "worker threads". If you mean thread-pool threads, then no, `System.Threading.Thread` creates new threads, rather than scheduling to the threads in the thread pool like `ThreadPool` and `Task` do.